# How can I call a related model in Mongoose mapreduce

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose

So it may be that mapreduce is not the best way to handle this but here's what I am trying to achieve.

I have a schema of events and a schema of venues.  Each event has multiple dates and 0/1 venue.  I want, on event save, to generate entries for each possible date and store that alongside the venue info in another collection - say occurrences.  But I have 2 questions/issues.

1. I seem to not be able to call external things from the map function even when using scope so my call to find the venue info fails.
2. Where is the best place to deal with generating an entry for each date?  Loop through dates in map and emit for each date? or in the reduce or finalize function?

Rather than just tell me that I cannot call a dbref from a mapreduce function I would prefer to find the most efficient solution to create, on event save, a collection of occurrences that contain the needed event/venue data. I am open to other methods but the code below should outline my needs.

```
    Event.pre('save', function (next) {

    var o = {};
    o.scope = {Venue: mongoose.model.Venue};
    o.map = function () {

      var data = {dates: this.dates};
      var self = this;
      if(this.venue) {
        Venue.view(this.venue, {}, function(err, doc) {
          if(doc) {
            data.venue_name = doc.name;
          }
          emit(self._id, data);
        });
      } else {
        emit(this._id, data);
      }
    };
    o.reduce = function (k, vals) {
      return vals;
    };
    o.out = { replace: 'occurrences' };
    o.verbose = true;
    mongoose.models.Event.mapReduce(o, function (err, model, stats) {
      next();
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

map/reduce operates on one collection at a time. My suggestion would be:

1. Map/Reduce over events and emit once for each date including the event ID and the venue ID (hopefully you have the venue Id in the events collection)
2. Query the resulting collection ("occurrences") for all records that have a venue ID, query venues for that document, and then update the "occurrences" document with the denormalized venue information.

Comment: Where do you propose querying occurrences/denormalizing the venue info?

Comment: You have to do a separate mongoose query for that after the event map/reduce is done.

Comment: If I do that outside of the MR then there is not much point to going through the map reduce process - just manually go through each event, get the venue and save the occurrences.

Comment: Well, the map/reduce will help you create the collection, but not sure what you want me to say. MongoDB does not have joins. This query is a join. Therefore, you must build it manually. It's a pain, but that's the tradeoff with mongodb and its ilk.

Comment: Ya I understand. I guess I'm trying to figure out if there are any benefits to MP compared to just doing it by hand. Guess I'll skip the entire process